# How to remove GitHub Pages?

Tags: github

I was playing about with my git repo and tried the GitHub pages feature but I'm not sure how to get rid of it. The check box on the repo admin is disabled.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simply delete the `gh-pages` remote branch:

```
$ git push origin :gh-pages
```

Comment: I'm not sure this answer is complete, now that GitHub pages supports different ways to create GitHub pages (master, /docs, etc.). By disabling GitHub pages in the repo settings (and Ctrl-F5 in my browser), I see the pages are gone.

Comment: How do you disable GitHub pages in the repo settings?  I have removed the cname's etc from cloudflare that were pointing to github, and when i go to repo > settings > github pages section, it just says "Your GitHub Pages site is currently being built from the master branch".  There doesn't seem to be anyway to `delete` or `disable` the github page, it still says "Your site is ready to be published at https://some-user-name.github.io/some-repo-name/." PS The `Source` section says `Branch: master` and then `/root`.

Comment: Answer to my own question, not sure if best practise, but I changed `Source` dropdown value to `None` and clicked `Save` and now it says `GitHub Pages is currently disabled. Select a source below to enable GitHub Pages for this repository.`  So I guess that worked.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me.  I've moved it back to "none" and pressed Save but I still see:  "github-pages Active " on my home page under Environments even though they all show 404 when I click on them.

Comment: Oh I've also tried this answer but it says "remote ref does not exist".

Answer (score 2):

Go to the GitHub Pages settings:

> repo -> settings -> pages

Change the ‘Source’ dropdown value to ‘None’, and ‘Save’ it. It will then say ‘GitHub Pages is currently disabled.

Comment: In my repo, it is now the Branch dropdown, not source. Other than that, this works :-).